# Idiomatic way to handle nested nullable objects in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm working with scala and recently inherited some Java code which needs to be grafted in and unfortunately rewriting it in Scala isn't in the cards. It has a deeply nested object structure, and any level can be null. Often I only care about the values deep within the nesting.

Ideally, I'd do something like this:

```
 Option(foo.blah.blarg.doh)
```

But if any of foo.blah.blarg is null, this will generate a NPE.

For now I've taken to wrapping it in a Try:

```
Try(Option(foo.blah.blarg.doh)).getOrElse(None)
```

Note that using .toOption doesn't work quite right as it can lead to a Some(null) if the final bit of the chain is null.

I'm not particularly fond of this construct, any other ideas out there?

Comment: if you can use scalaz then this will make your life easier to deal with exception in a monadic way and get exception message.

     def yourMethod  = \/.fromTryCatch {
        Option(foo.blah.blarg.doh)
     }

where `yourMethod` returns disjunction `\/[Throwable,Option[T]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take advantage of by-name parameters to build your own construct:

```
def handleNull[T](x: => T): Option[T] = try Option(x) catch {
  case _: NullPointerException => None
}

handleNull(foo.blah.blarg.doh)
```

Answer (score 9):

flatMap it:

```
for {
  a <- Option(foo)
  b <- Option(a.blah)
  c <- Option(b.blarg)
  d <- Option(c.doh)
} yield d
```

Comment: I realize that FTS as a phrase is itself idiomatic :) - however, this is a case where I'm not digging it as much. There are a lot of these end points and every one is going to involve several lines of code to get at them using this mechanism.

If there was a way to generalize this pattern so it was write once and use anywhere (involving different nests, etc) I'd like it a lot more but that's beyond my scala-fu.

Comment: with dynamic+macros you could convert something like `DynAccess(foo).blah.blarg.doh` to a for comprehension/some null checks. But I don't have the time to write it at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `cats` library in your project, you may use it's extension methods:

```
  import cats.implicits._

  Either
    .catchOnly[NullPointerException](foo.blah.blarg.doh)
    .collectFirstSome(Option(_))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this method to safely navigate through a chain of calls where every step can return null. Its more convenient to use than Options and flatMaps.

```
  /**
    * @param expr expression which is a chain of java calls
    * @tparam A the type of the last expression
    * @return Some(A) if there was no null, None otherwise
    */
  def safeTraverseNullableChain[A](expr: => A): Option[A] = {
    Try(expr).filter(_ != null).toOption
  }
```